# Why are the flower buds in my pepper plant wilting and falling off prematurely?

Tags: vegetables, flowers, peppers, chili

[image]

[image]

I'm growing long Indian pepper variety. I have taking good care of my pepper plant by regularly fertilizing them every 30 days using npk 20:20:20 and applying liquid seaweed every 15 days with the recommended does. I water them only when the top 2 inches of the soil feels slightly dry. Overall the plant looks healthy but only the top part seems to have some issues. Only 20% of the flower buds are blooming and rest of them are dropping off prematurely. The plant receives direct sunlight for 5-6 hrs a day and the temperature fluctuate between 70 to 90 degree Fahrenheit throughout the day. So far plant has produced no chilly. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're feeding too much nitrogen. Excess nitrogen can express itself as flower drop in chiles. I'd recommend stopping the 20/20/20 for a bit and then starting something much lighter like a 5/3/3.